# Passing reference to a variable in another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to learn unity.  This is something I would use in Javascript so I was hoping to find a way to do this in C#, where you take the collision variable and use the reference to have another function clean up the variables after you are finished.

**Edit**

I have been practicing since posting this, I am trying to pass a reference to another class to handle the turn on and off of the variable.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")) {
        PowerUpRoutine(ref collision.gameObject.GetComponent<enemy>().powerup);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        PowerUpRoutine(ref collision.gameObject.GetComponent<player>().powerup);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine(float target) {
    target = 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    target = 0;
}
```

I have also tried not passing powerup, but just the object and it still errors.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?

---

**Original**

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")) {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<enemy>().powerup = 1;

        StartCoroutine(removePower(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<enemy>()));
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<player>().powerup = 1;
        

        StartCoroutine(removePower(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<player>()));
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

IEnumerator removePower(GameObject target) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    target.powerup = 0;
}
```

Comment: Your new idea won't work either of course ... `float` is a value type, not a reference .. IEnumerators can't take `ref` parameters .. is there something wrong with the 3 solutions I provided?

Comment: I had not been online yet to read your response,  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First if all there is a general flaw in your approach: When you

```
 Destroy(gameObject);
```

this object this component is attached to then also all Coroutines are immediately canceled.

I would therefore start the coroutine rather on the target itself (see example below).

---

And then your classes should have a common interface or base class like for example

#### Solution 1 - Common Base Class

```
public abstract class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float powerup;

    // And other common members
}
```

And then you inherit

```
public class Player : Character 
{
    // Additional player specific stuff
}
```

and

```
public class Enemy : Character
{
    // Additional enemy specific stuff
}
```

#### Solution 2 - Common Interface

if you rather want to go for an interface

```
public interface ICharacter
{
    float powerup { get; set; }
}
```

And then both your classes have to implement that

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour, ICharacter 
{
    public float powerup { get; set; }

    // Additional player specific stuff
}
```

and

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour, ICharacter 
{
    public float powerup { get; set; }

    // Additional player specific stuff
}
```

---

And then your collision code could simply be

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision) 
{
    // TryGetComponent now finds anything inherited from Character
    // you don't even need to check the tags
    if(collision.TryGetComponent<Character>(out var character)) 
    // Or if using the interface
    //if(collision.TryGetComponent<ICharacter>(out var character)
    {
        // Let the character run this coroutine without even having to know what it does
        character.StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine(character));

        // This is now ok and not terminating the Coroutine since the routine is run by character itself
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine(Character target) 
// or if using the interface accordingly
//IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine(ICharacter target) 
{
    // Have in mind though that this routine is now running on a different object
    // at a time where this component is already destroyed => You can't reference to anything of this component in here!

    target.powerup = 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    target.powerup = 0;
}
```

---

#### Solution 3 - Simple Overload

Or as last resort if the before two is not an option for whatever reason you could of course also simply have two overloads

```
IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine(Player target)
{
    target.powerup = 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    target.powerup = 0;
}

IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine(Enemy target)
{
    target.powerup = 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    target.powerup = 0;
}
```

and then do

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision) 
{
    if(collision.TryGetComponent<Player>(out var player)) 
    {
        player.StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine(player));

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else if(collision.TryGetComponent<Enemy>(out var enemy)) 
    {
        enemy.StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine(enemy));

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still doing the unity tutorials, I just find what they guy is teaching to be entirely to simplistic and I am trying to add functionality and learn how to actually make things in Unity.

So, right now I have a spawner class that handles both the spawning of Enemies and the spawning of powerups.   They both are prefabs that they have own bit of code.  All I was hoping to do was pass the collision reference in order to just set that variable, but it makes complete sense that it stops immediately upon destruction.

Comment: Is it possible to do this instead? 

PowerUpRoutine(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<player>(out var player))

And that just has:

(GameObject target) {
        target.powerup = 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        target.powerup = 0;

The error I get is "No overload for method Get Component"

Comment: it makes no sense to only pass on the `GameObject` since `GameObject` has no `.powerup` ;) And if anything it would be `collision.gameObject.GetComponent<player>()` but then your parameter would need to be a `Player` not a `GameObject` ... I addressed this issue in the long code examples -> use a common base class or use two different Coroutines

Comment: That's amazing thank you.  What makes no sense to me is how can you have 2 IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine but becuase you tell it the type of variable to input it knows which to take in.  It seems to work great, again I am still new to Unity, what is the... best method to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Unity but is called overloading of a method ;) and the compiler chose which is the best match for the given parameter(s). You decide which of these is the best solution for you ... Personally I would go with the first but that depends of course on your project and how clean you want/need to go ... sometimes quick and dirty is allowed for prototyping ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Coroutines are also stopped when the MonoBehaviour is destroyed or if the GameObject the MonoBehaviour is attached to is disabled.

You should destroy the gameobject when the coroutine finishes.

```
StartCoroutine(removePower(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<enemy>()));
//Destroy(gameObject);

IEnumerator removePower(GameObject target) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    target.powerup = 0;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

---

Or run the coroutine on another gameobject

```
var enemy = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<enemy>();
enemy.StartCoroutine(removePower(enemy));
```

Comment: The second one is course correct but is only half of the answer since it doesn't address the main question which is about the type to be passed on to the IEnumerator